# Heroku "/send" POST request resulting in 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

When deploying app to Heroku the front end seems to be working flawlessly. The problem I have is a express/node backend with endpoint ". /send" witch just sends the inputted content to me in an email with there contact importation. Essentially a contact Form. It worked perfectly fine on Localhost and the email was sent. Once I uploaded it to Heroku I've spent 2 days troubleshooting and can't figure it out.

Error is as follows:

```
POST https://portfolio-appp-1999.herokuapp.com/send 404 (Not Found)
```

```
contact.js:24 Response: Response {type: 'basic', url: 'https://portfolio-appp-
1999.herokuapp.com/send', redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
contact.js:
```

`30 Error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

Server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { require('dotenv').config() }

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(router); // remove "/" path
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
router.use(bodyParser.json());


const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
  secureConnection: false,
  port: 587,
  service: 'outlook',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
  },
  tls: {
    ciphers: 'SSLv3'
  }
});

const noReplyEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "outlook",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
  }
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("contactEmail is ready to send")
  }
});

noReplyEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("noReplyEmail is ready to send")
  }
});


router.post("https://portfolio-appp-1999.herokuapp.com/send", (req, res) => {
  const { name, useremail, message } = req.body;

  console.log("name:", name);
  console.log("useremail:", useremail);
  console.log("message:", message);

  const mail = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    to: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    subject: "New Contact from Portfolio Page",
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p><p>Email: ${useremail}</p><p>Message: ${message}</p>`
  };
  
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({ status: "ERROR" });
    } else {
      console.log("Mail sent successfully!");
      res.json({ status: "Message Sent "});
    }
  });
});
```

contact.js component:

```
React, { useState } from "react";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("submit");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");
    const { name, useremail, message } = e.target.elements;
    let details = {
      name: name.value,
      useremail: useremail.value,
      message: message.value,
    };
    console.log("Details:", details);
    try {
      let response = await fetch("https://portfolio-appp-1999.herokuapp.com/send", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(details),
      });
      console.log("Response:", response);
      setStatus("submit");
      let result = await response.json();
      console.log("Result:", result);
      alert(result.status);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error:", error);
      setStatus("submit");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="body-Container">
      <h2>Contact Me Below.</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="useremail">Your Email:</label>
          <input type="email" id="useremail" required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="message">Message:</label>
          <textarea id="message" required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">{status}</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};


export default ContactForm;
```

.env

```
EMAIL_USER=xxxxxxxxx@outlook.com
EMAIL_PASS=xxxxxxxxxx
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried changing to endpoints to examapleapp.herokuapp.com/send and just using /send
Updated config variables in every way I can think of. Double checked that the process.env.PORT is working fine Which I believe it is.

This is first time deploying an app to any hosting so if the solution is obvious my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST route in `server.js` is wrong. Actually is:
`router.post("https://portfolio-appp-1999.herokuapp.com/send", (req, res) => {[...]`
but must be:
`router.post("/send", (req, res) => { [... all other stuff]`

Take a look at [Express routing docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Yes, I actually changed that. Still having the same problem. Should my component just use a fetch request to “/send” or the full url?

Comment: try with full url

Comment: Yea, just tried it with both still getting “404 error “ 3 days troubleshooting this.

Comment: Maybe you must rebuild all your stuff in Heroku. 404 is a clear response... Not found